# What font does my system uses?

Tags: fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 18.10 with dwm. I have removed almost all GUI programs provided by the default desktop environment Gnome. Now, my system uses a font that I want to use in my terminal, but for that I need to know the name of the font. How do I know what font it is?

Here is a demo of the font used by chromium, same as my system.

[image: demo of the font]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font used by applications is often selected not directly by name, but because it's first in the list for the `sans-serif` generic alias in your system (according to FontConfig files in /etc/fonts).

```
$ fc-match sans-serif

$ fc-match -s sans-serif | head
```

Assuming you're referring to Chromium's *chrome* and not the document, in most Linux distributions that's most likely "DejaVu Sans" (or something closely related, e.g. "Bitstream Vera Sans").

```
$ pango-view --font="DejaVu Sans 10" --text="What font does my system..."
```

Comment: Both `Sans-serif` and `DejaVu Sans` look the same. Maybe DejaVu Sans is one of the Sans-serif family. But they don't really look good in terminal, why is that? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Because they're variable-width fonts, so you have letters like "i" "j" much narrower than average, and letters like "m" wider than average. Terminals consist of a character grid, where all columns are fixed-width, so they need a specially-designed monospace font with all letters having the same width, too. Try `DejaVu Sans Mono` instead.